# check if value in column is date, and then do something with it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a column that holds a rejected reason for a person.
The value is either something like "Person refused" or "10/18/2012"

I'm trying to setup my query to check if the value is a date, then it can put a blank space in its place. Otherwise, keep the text that's in there.

The query that I setup is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id, 
CASE description
  WHEN ISDATE(description) THEN ''
END AS refuseReason
    FROM person
```

But this returns an error. If the dates themselves are saved as VARCHAR, then would I have to convert them first to a date, then check to see if ISDATE? If I did that, would it convert the text when it comes accross that?

EDIT: I tried it by casting it to datetime, and i keep getting error as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id, 
CASE description
  WHEN ISDATE(CAST(OBSVALUE AS DATETIME)) THEN ''
END AS refuseReason
    FROM person
```

Comment: If you have the power to do so, *fix your schema*!  Having a single column that is either a string or a date is a *Really really bad idea*!

Comment: I totally agree Flimzy. Unfortunately that is out of my control :(

Comment: I don't even understand how a date can be a reason.

Comment: haha, you and me both Aaron. I just query the data, I don't ask what their processes for storing it are :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming TSQL) [IsDate()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) returns 1 or 0. (Also your CASE syntax was incorrect)

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id, 
CASE 
  WHEN ISDATE(description) = 1 THEN ''
  ELSE description
END AS refuseReason
    FROM person
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you sir! I knew I was on the right track with the ISDATE() function, but thank you for helping me refine it :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted if solution was useful. And if you do get a chance to store date in a separate DateTime field (I know you cannot at this time) please do so, it will help to avoid many headaches.

Comment: Done and Done. And I wish I could store the date in a separate column as DateTime. This problem would be non-existant. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The ISDATE() functions returns a boolean 1 or 0
you have to make the clause by using

```
WHEN ISDATE(@variable) = 1 THEN ''
ELSE @variable
```